# improved where clause

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, where-clause

I want to write a where clause in an sql stored procedure with this functionality.

```
if (@userId=0)
begin
    SELECT * from tblUsers
end
else
begin
    SELECT * from tblUsers
    WHERE userId= @userId
end
```

when I send an `id(example:123)` to stored procedure it should bring me specific one, when I send "0" as an id it should return whole data
But I don't want to use if else. there should be something which I can improve my where clause.

for example

```
SELECT * from tblUsers
WHERE (userId= @userId OR @userId = 0) and @userId = 123... bla bla
```

(or course this is not)

any help?

Comment: Why is the 2nd code snippet not acceptable?

Comment: The second query (but without the `and @userId...` bit) seems what you want. By the way, it's usually recommended that you indicate the absence of a value using `NULL` rather than making up your own sentinel values - it's what it's there for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just for suggestion if you pass null in @userid than you can do like this easily

```
SELECT * from tblUsers
    WHERE userId= Isnull(@userId,userId)
```

this avoid extra condition ...just pass @useId=null if there is no data or you can do like this

```
if (@userId=0)
  select @userId = null
SELECT * from tblUsers
    WHERE userId= Isnull(@userId,userId)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use case condition in where clause:

```
SELECT 
  * 
from 
  tblUsers
WHERE
  userId=(case when @userId=0 then userId else @userId end)
```